# request-channel in inbound-gateway pointing to wrong version class

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am migrating from spring integration 3.0.3 to spring integration 4.0.2.release and in my springIntegration.xml, I have defined a inbound-gateway (it was already there) but in that request-channel is pointing to version 3 class.

inbound gateway is

```
<integration-jms:inbound-gateway id="jmsInBoundA"
                                     container="jmsListenerA"
                                     auto-startup="true"
                                     reply-delivery-persistent="false"
                                     reply-priority="7"
                                     message-converter="logMsgConverter"
                                     extract-request-payload="true"
                                     explicit-qos-enabled-for-replies="true"
                                     reply-time-to-live="30000"
                                     reply-timeout="70000"
                                     extract-reply-payload="true"
                                     request-channel="inputChannel"
                                     error-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

But it is showing the error
 "Cannot resolve required base class 'or.springframework.integration.MessageChannel'. I am not sure why is pointing to this class from integration package while it should use messaging package as per updated version automatically from classpath.

in pom.xml, I have defined:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

We are using spring version 4.0.3 with this. Please help me to resolve this problem as even after changing to spring 4 why springintegration.xml is pointing to a class of spring 3.

And my all integration tests are failing as I am getting this error in stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/springIntegration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:235)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.config.PublisherRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(PublisherRegistrar.java:67)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationRegistrar.registerMessagingAnnotationPostProcessors(IntegrationRegistrar.java:319)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(IntegrationRegistrar.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.AnnotationConfigParser.parse(AnnotationConfigParser.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.parse(AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't show any StackTrace, I guess that your IDE complains.

I see the same from my IDEA 13.1:
[image]

So, just ignore it, because IDEs don't support Spring Integration XSD 4.0, yet.

**UPDATE**

Good catch! It is really a **bug**. Whouldn't you mind to raise a JIRA issue (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter?

From other side it is a different question and I'll help you there with some workaround to get dir that `NPE`. Link it here and let's `accept` this answer to mark the question as resolved. I mean the IDEA issue.

Comment: For the record, for schema validation, the spring tools for eclipse (STS) finds the proper schema on the class path using metadata in the jar, so it doesn't need to be upgraded (at least for this issue) when a new version of Spring projects are released.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. now I will think in another direction. I have added the stack trace in my question (edited). Everything is working fine with spring-integration 3.0.3 but when upgrading to 4.0.0 or later, it is giving me xml parsing error in springIntegration.xml. Please help.

Comment: Jira issue INT-3445 created. Please help me to get over NTE